# The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.13.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0-rc2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

How do I update Android Gradle in Adroid Studio? I'm using Android Studio 0.9.9.

I'm getting this error when I try to run my Android project:

```
Error:The project is using an unsupported version of the Android Gradle plug-in (0.13.2). The recommended version is 1.0.0-rc2.
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and re-import project</a>
```

**update:**

clicking the fix link that shows up brings this up:

```
Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'HelloWorld' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking the fix link that shows up?

Comment: Please check out my update ianhanniballake. Thanks for the reply.